# reversing an HDL file

Tags: file-format

I was given an HDL file with the following content:

> `CHIP Box { !     IN in[128]; !     OUT out[128]; !  !     PARTS: !     Xor(a=in[0..31], b=in[96..127], out=red); !     Xor(a=in[32..63], b=in[64..95], out=king); !     Xor(a=in[64..95], b=in[96..127], out=dave); !     Concat(a=in[0..31], b=dave, c=red, d=king, out=ayk); !     Switch(a=ayk[3..6], b=ayk[19..22]); !     Switch(a=ayk[54..61], b=ayk[32..39]); !     Switch(a=ayk[63..70], b=ayk[120..127]); !     Switch(a=ayk[95..98], b=ayk[81..84]); !     Xor(a=ayk[0..31], b=ayk[64..95], out=earl); !     Xor(a=ayk[64..95], b=ayk[96..127], out=cosmo); !     Xor(a=ayk[32..63], b=ayk[96..127], out=abbott); !     Concat(a=abbott, b=comso, c=ayk[0..31], d=earl, out=phoenix); !     Reverse(in=phoenix, out=out); }`

i was asked to reverse it and retrieve the value of `in` , how can i do it please knowing that i have the value of `out`? thanks

Comment: Hey! Great question. Glad to see you're enjoying TAMUctf which we spent quite a long time creating, but as this is an active competition, maybe don't post it on StackExchange... :)